# Improving Performance of a Co-Simulation Adams/Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, fmi

I would like to Co-Simulate a Multibody-System (generated in MSC Adams) with a Controller in Matlab (as shown on [this](https://www.mathworks.com/products/connections/product_detail/adams-controls.html) Matlab Website). The Co-Simulation itself is working, however at an incredible slow speed, due to the FMU created from the Multibody-System in Adams. I realized, however that my processor/RAM uses only 15% of its capacity, so there is plenty of processing power left.

Therefore, my question:
Is it possible to increase the simulation speed of the Multibody-System FMU by using the full computational power of my pc? (Maybe parallel computing in Adams or similar approaches?)

Thank you for your answers!

Some technical infos:

- I am using Adams 2019.2 (Adams View) and Matlab2019.b
- I am running on an FMU interface in Matlab ([see here](https://www.mathworks.com/products/connections/product_detail/adams-controls.html))
- I have no flexible bodies
- I am using a communication interval of 10ms and a BDF Solver
- I am running on an Intel Core i7-6700K and 64 GB RAM

Comment: Both Links that you provide above point to the native Adams-Simulink co-simulation, not to the FMU export of Adams.
One problem is, that the DAE of Adams see discontinuites every 10ms and has to re-start from there. This enourmously slows down computation compared to a smooth simultion.
Is your co-simulation setup suitable? That is, have you selected appropriate coupling variables and an appropriate macro timestep?
Could you use Adams as importing tools instead and create the FMU from Simulink (with Simulink Coder or FMI-kit + Simulink Coder?